# How to write proper tests when using an API wrapper that makes calls to a third party library?

Tags: ruby, api, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I am just getting into RSpec and proper unit testing in Ruby. 
In my current project I need to make calls to the Yelp API. 
To make the actual calls I use the [yelpster](https://github.com/nvd/yelpster) API wrapper for Yelp.

Since I am new to unit testing I am unsure on how to properly approach writing tests when using a third party API. 
I found a number of tutorials on [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), which won't be the right fit since I am using a wrapper.

**So how should I approach testing, e.g. when writing a method which should return a certain number of search results?**

Obviously I would like to eliminate the actual calls to the remote API, e.g. as can be done when using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr), but again this library seems to be used when directly accessing the API via HTTP POST/GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stub or mock your calls to the third-party library using [RSpec's mocking library](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) (or another mocking library, if you prefer).

The correct use of stubs and mocks is a big topic, but generally you'll want to stub when you're reading from the API and want to feed your tests known data, and you'll want to mock when you're writing to the API and want to verify that you've made some call. At first glance yelpster looks read-only, so you'll probably want to stub.

If it takes a series of API calls (or just method calls on API-wrapper classes) to get one useful thing done, consider moving each series of calls into a method on an API wrapper wrapper (so to speak) class. You'll then have less methods to stub.

For example, with yelpster (copying from the documentation) you need to do this to search:

```
client = Yelp::Client.new
request = Location.new(
  :address => '650 Mission St',
  :city => 'San Francisco',
  :state => 'CA',
  :radius => 2,
  :term => 'cream puffs')
response = client.search(request)
```

You could wrap that in

```
class YelpService
  def self.search(options)
    Yelp::Client.new.search(Location.new(options))
  end
end
```

and stub it with

```
YelpService.stub(:search) { "the response" }
```